# Headphone Sound Balance Problem

Tags: 16.04, sound, headphones

The sound balance between **Left** and **Right** of my headphone gets shifted (almost completely) towards the **Right** each time I restart my PC.

Using ***Ubuntu Studio 16.04.1***.
Not exactly a serious problem but still kind of annoying.
Any ideas???????